# Adding functionality to a default copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have a question. Say I have a class A, for which I'm perfectly happy with the default copy constructor.

Can I add functionality to this default copy constructor without re-writing all its work again?

Trivial example:

```
class A 
{
public:
A(int n) : data(n) { };
private:
int data;
};
```

Suppose I want to print the message "Copy constructor!" each time a copy constructor is called. For this simple case I would just write my own copy constructor, which takes charge of the shallow copy explicitly, and also prints out the message. Is there a way to add the message printing (or whatever other functionality I want) *on top* of the default copy constructor, without writing explictly the shallow coyp?

Comment: You may do something like [this](https://ideone.com/hUJ9x3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I want to print the message "Copy constructor!" each time a copy constructor is called. For this simple case I would just write my own copy constructor, which takes charge of the shallow copy explicitly, and also prints out the message.

Yes, you need to provide your copy constructor explicitely and add that printing out the message.

```
class A 
{
    public:
    A(int n) : data(n) { };
    // You need to add tis:
    A(const& A rhs) : data(rhs.data)  {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor!" << '\n';
    }
    private:
    int data;
};
```

> Is there a way to add the message printing (or whatever other functionality I want) on top of the default copy constructor, without writing explictly the shallow coyp?

No, there isn't.

Comment: You actually forget to copy `data`, you just do the extension.

Comment: And something like [this](https://ideone.com/hUJ9x3) allow to add functionality on top of default copy constructor.

Comment: This is bad practice; you need to remember to add the copying every time you add a member. Single responsibility rule should be applied here.

Comment: @sp2danny _"Single responsibility rule should be applied here."_ Can you elaborate please? A private `init()` function or what?

Comment: I would suggest a member, whose only purpose is to be loud about being copied, that way the containing class can have all special members implicitly defaulted.

Comment: @sp2danny I wouldn't like such overengineering.